# Benchmarking in a cusom pallet requires a storage put operation in Staking pallet

Tags: pallet, benchmarking, benchmark, pallet-staking

Let's say I have a pallet_x. In this pallet i have an extrinsic where I get the active_era using the below code :

```
            Staking::<T>::active_era()
                          .map(|e| e.index)
                          .ok_or(Error::<T>::FailedToGetActiveEra)?
```

So when I write benchmark for this extrinsic it fails with this error **FailedToGetActiveEra**

My question now is how to insert value to ActiveEra storage in pallet_staking from pallet_x ?

Comment: does `pallet_staking::ActiveEra::<T>::mutate/insert( .. )` help? Also make sure to include `T: pallet_staking::Config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the same way as in tests, by inserting storage items like @Purple_Turtle posted in the comment;

```rust
pallet_staking::ActiveEra::<T>::put(…)
```

One example would be from the [nomination-pools](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/32ab5cbeb29f68a1977e4803fe8c0731fe5c99be/frame/nomination-pools/benchmarking/src/lib.rs#L395) benchmark where it fudges the staking stoarge.

Normally it is better to have pallets communicate with each other via traits, since otherwise storage invariants can get invalidated when `pallet_x` just modifies the storage of `pallet_y` without its knowledge. But if you only do it in testing/benchmarks, then its fine.

Since that type has private fields, you can hack around it by decoding it from its struct elements. It's not ideal, but better than having to go through an upstream change:

```rust
#[test]
fn hack() {
    use codec::{Encode, Decode};
    
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        let raw = (4 as sp_staking::EraIndex, Some(10u64)).encode();
        let info = pallet_staking::ActiveEraInfo::decode(&mut &raw[..]).unwrap();
        // Now you can put it into stoarge.
        pallet_staking::ActiveEra::<Test>::put(&info);
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem is one of the fields in ActiveEraInfo struct is private which is not allowing me to storage put. pub struct ActiveEraInfo {
 pub index: EraIndex,
 start: Option<u64>,
}

Comment: Ah that is annoying indeed. I extended the answer.